# java string replaceall regular expression

Tags: java, regex, string, replaceall

I have string (mystring) as below containing double quote:

```
String mystring = "my regex expression checked=\"someword_and_moreword_value\"";
```

expected output:

```
mystring = "my regex expression";
```

tried with following, did not get expected output:

```
mystring = mystring.replaceAll("[checked=\\w*_value]", "");
```

Comment: What *is* your expected output?

Comment: What do you think `[]` are in regex?

Comment: its there in question

Comment: Thanks Andy Brown and Sotirios Delimanolis. If I would have time to read whole regex thing, i would not have come here. Everything is there in book. Sometime, we just need quick answer like one given by @vks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
checked=.*?_value\\"
```

Try this.Remember `[]` is a character class .See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vD5iH9/27